# how can i run ffmpeg command in background php

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Hello guys i am building a web app with php, i want to add watermark to a video with ffmpeg but due the process do take time to finish, i want to run it in the background, here is the command that i used

```
$hidey=" 2>/dev/null >/dev/null &"; 

$cmd="ffmpeg -i $video_name -i watermark.jpg -filter_complex overlay=W-w-5:H-h-15[video];[video]drawtext=\"text=$text:fontcolor=white:fontsize=10:x=(w-text_w)-5: y=(h-text_h)-5\" $new_file 
    $hidey"; 

shell_exec("$cmd")
```

the above command does not work, i dont know why, what did i do wrong

I also tried `var_dump(shell_exec("$cmd"))`, so that i can get the error, it gave me NULL

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: no error, it just didn't run work, i tried var_dump(shell_exec("$cmd"));, it gave me NULL

Comment: You're hiding the output from ffmpeg, so you won't get an error from ffmpeg. Assuming ffmpeg is even being executed, but that is unknown.

Comment: @llogan if i should run it without the `2>/dev/null >/dev/null &` it will run successfully but it takes a lot of time that's why i want to run it in the background and its not working

Comment: Try using the `-d` option instead of the redirects: `ffmpeg -d -i …`

Comment: its still not working, it does not add the watermark to the video

Comment: Unfortunately "not working" is not enough to work with and is not descriptive. We need errors, logs, anything. There is nothing I can suggest without it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218468/discussion-between-js-doee-and-llogan).

Comment: its not giving me any error, you can run the command in your system, it works well without `2>/dev/null >/dev/null &` it will run successfully, but if i add it, it will output `NULL`

Comment: ok, Can you help me on how to run this command in the background `$cmd="ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.jpg -filter_complex overlay=W-w-5:H-h-15[video];[video]drawtext=\"text=$text:fontcolor=white:fontsize=10:x=(w-text_w)-5: y=(h-text_h)-5\" new_video.mp4"; 

shell_exec("$cmd")`

Comment: I don't know anything about PHP. I only know ffmpeg. At this point I don't even know i your ffmpeg command is working. You should run the same command that the PHP script executes, but do it unscripted in a command line interface. Once you confirm that ffmpeg is working then you can attempt to add it to your PHP. The -d option in ffmpeg enabled "daemon" mode making it run "in the background". You saying that it "doesn't work" possibly indicates the problem is likely with your PHP scripting and not ffmpeg.